# Dynamically added TextViews, new line

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Im creating dynamically list of TextViews in LinearLayout.

```
foreach (var category in item.categories)
{
    var textSimilarArtist = new TextView(context) { Text = category.title };
    var layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent,
          ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent) { LeftMargin = 20 };
    textSimilarArtist.LayoutParameters = layoutParams;
    view.FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.categoriesLayout).AddView(textSimilarArtist);
}
```

The problem is if there are many TextViews the last is not starting in new line but creating something like "column". How can I make TextViews starting in new line after there is no enough space for next one?